# How do you make "Again" statements in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm new to programming and Stack Overflow, but I'm making something that has to do with pressing a key to do something, and it works but I don't know how to enable it so that it stops doing the command.

```
function scarf (mode, key, foo) {
if ((mode === 1) && foo) {
    $(key).keypress = play(key);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code and elaborate a bit more? It's not clear what you mean.

Comment: Sounds like he wants to trigger it once and then more, then on the other hand the title is completely misleading

Comment: @alexdd55 I meant if you press the key again.

Comment: Sorry, please edit your question. I am sure, that a good answer is possible to make

Comment: You want the key event to happen only once, is this what you want?

Comment: If yes, then use this http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: What does the `play(key)` function?

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = (false);
function scarf(mode,foo,key,a) {
while ((mode === 1) && foo && b) {
    $(key).keypress = play(key);
    (a);
  }
}
while (a) {
$(key).keypress = stop(key);
(a = false);
}
```

I've figured it out.

Comment: What is `b`, where does it come from? And how is this `while ((mode === 1) && foo && b) {...}` not an infinite loop? I don't see that any of the conditions could change inside the loop. And the second `while (a) {` should be a `if (a) {`. Maybe the first loop too?